# Выбор файла через FileManager Android

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

Как сделать так, чтобы в приложении при нажатии на кнопку открывался файловый менеджер для выбора файла и путь к этому файлу внести в поле `EditText`?
Подобно тому, как вы в интернете на сайте выгружаете файл, и при нажатии на форму открывается файловый менеджер вашего устройства.

Comment: @eugeneek зато там реализация отличается, да и цели достигаются разные. А название примерно звучит одинаково.

Comment: @LexHobbit Цель у авторов одна, получить путь к файлу, выбранному через какое либо установленное приложение файлового менеджера.  И вы можете ответить на тот вопрос, добавив свою реализацию. Для этого и закрываются дубликаты, чтобы все решения одного вопроса были в одном месте.